# Build a proportions tree in R

Tags: r

I want to design an algorithm in R that, given a data frame of factors, it returns a tree of proportions where the base is the number of rows of the data frame (observations).

For instance, imagine that the amount of rows of my data frame is 100 and I have 4 factors. The first factor splits the observations in two levels, each of which has 50% of the obervations. Then, the next factor splits each of the previous levels in 4 levels and so on for the other two factors. Of course, the proportions for each leaf doesn't have to be equal.

How could I achieve that? I've been trying several ways but I'm a bit stuck.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what the output should be, but this problem seems to be recursive to me, so here is a recursive approach.  Say you have a `data.frame` of factors, and you want to split the data by factors in each column, left to right.  This function will do that, resulting in a list of "leaves" corresponding to data from the last column, split by the various groupings of factors in the previous columns.

```
## Sample data
set.seed(0)
dat <- setNames(data.frame(matrix(sample(0:1, 75, rep=T), 25, 3)),
                paste0("f", 1:3))
dat[] <- lapply(dat, as.factor)

f <- function(data) {
    if (NCOL(data) < 2L) return( split(data, data) )
    lapply(split(data[,-1L], data[,1L]), f)
}

## Apply function
res <- f(dat)

## Proportions at each leaf
## The naming is: column1.column2.column3. etc.
rapply(res, function(x) length(x)/nrow(dat))
# 0.0.0 0.0.1 0.1.0 0.1.1 1.0.0 1.0.1 1.1.0 1.1.1 
#  0.08  0.08  0.24  0.04  0.16  0.16  0.16  0.08 

## Counts
rapply(res, function(x) length(x))
# 0.0.0 0.0.1 0.1.0 0.1.1 1.0.0 1.0.1 1.1.0 1.1.1 
#     2     2     6     1     4     4     4     2 

## For example, the data corresponding to 1.1.0,
with(dat, dat[f1==1 & f2==1 & f3==0,])
#    f1 f2 f3
# 5   1  1  0
# 8   1  1  0
# 18  1  1  0
# 22  1  1  0
```

Comment: Yes! That is exactly what I needed. Thanks! Now I'd need to make a graph out of the counts (or the proportions), with a mother node and the leafs streaming down from it. How could I do it? I've been browsing through the igraph package tutorials but I've been unable so far to find a satisfactory result.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think the function would need to modified a bit to store information about each level.  You might want to ask a new question so people are more likely to see this new question (even better if you had an image of the output you had in mind).

Comment: Here we go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32033835/proportions-tree-graph-in-r