# Proportions tree graph in R

Tags: r, graph, tree

I need to build an algorithm that, given a `data.frame` made up of n factors, returns a tree graph where each node represents a level of a factor and the proportion of rows classified by the level of that factor and by the level of the upper nodes (for example, each node could display: factorX.levelY=30%).

The first node will represent the total number of rows and will be the base (100). The second level of the tree will have k nodes that will correspond to the k levels of the first factor, the third level will have k*m nodes, where m will be the levels of the second factor. And so on.

The 'data.frame' used as input for the function will have its columns ordered in a way that will serve as the hierarchy of the nodes. For instance, `data[,1]` will be the upper level factor in the tree, `data[,2]` and so on.

Here's an example of the `data.frame` that would be used as input:

```
 df<-data.frame( f1=factor( rep( LETTERS[1:2], each=50)),  
                 f2=rep( letters[1:4], each=25),
                 f3=rep( colors(1)[1:2], 25, each=2))
```

The graph would look like these, but with the format inside the nodes indicated before: (factorX.levelY=30%)

[image]

I've noticed that the `rpart` package can produce similar graphs, but the only input that functions accept is a model object type.

Comment: Have a look at the `igraph` package.

Comment: I already did, but I'm unable to implement it properly.

Comment: Well, could you provide an example of your dataframe?

Comment: @Hav0k done! If there is anything else you need to know just ask.

Comment: It seems like this requires quite some coding. I will play around with it a little, but I can't promise a solution soon.

Comment: The `partykit` package could also be leveraged to draw a similar graph. See `vignette(“partykit“, package = “partykit“)` for a simple introductory example.

Comment: When Achim speaks, people (should) listen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a recursive approach.  First, there is a function to build the tree structure, gathering the proportions at each split level into a named, nested list.  Second, there is a function to convert the nested list to an edgelist to use with `igraph`.  Lastly, `igraph` provides the plotting capability.

```
## Create tree structure in nested list
makePtree <- function(data, prev=1) {
    tab <- (t <- table(data[,1L]))[t>0] / nrow(data)*prev                     # calculate proportions at current level
    ns <- sprintf("%s.%s=%.2f", names(data)[1L], names(tab), unname(c(tab)))  # names
    if (NCOL(data) < 2L) return( ns )                                         # we are done, return names only
    setNames(mapply(makePtree, split(data[,-1L,drop=F], data[,1L], drop=T),
                    tab, SIMPLIFY = F), ns)                                   # recurse
}

## Create edgelist from nested list for igraph::graph_from_data_frame
lst2edge <- function(lst) {
    if (!is.list(lst)) return( data.frame(a=character(0), b=character(0)) )
    do.call(rbind,
            c(lapply(names(lst), function(x) {
                if (!is.list(lst[[x]])) return( data.frame(a=x, b=lst[[x]]) )
                data.frame(a=x, b=names(lst[[x]]))
            }), lapply(lst, lst2edge)))
}

## Apply functions
lst <- makePtree(df)                                   # nested list
dat <- lst2edge(lst)                                   # edgelist
dat <- rbind(dat, data.frame(a="root", b=names(lst)))  # add a root node 

## Make an igraph
library(igraph)
g <- graph_from_data_frame(dat)
plot(g, layout=layout.reingold.tilford(g, root="root"))
```

[image]

If you wanted the final nodes to be represented separately you could alter their names so `igraph` points to them separately.  Here, I modified the `lst2edge` function to produce longer names for the final level.  Then use some regex to shorten them for the final figure.

```
## Create edgelist from nested list for igraph::graph_from_data_frame
lst2edge <- function(lst) {
    if (!is.list(lst)) return( data.frame(a=character(0), b=character(0)) )
    do.call(rbind,
            c(lapply(names(lst), function(x) {
                if (!is.list(lst[[x]])) return( data.frame(a=x, b=paste0(x, lst[[x]])) )
                data.frame(a=x, b=names(lst[[x]]))
            }), lapply(lst, lst2edge)))
}

## Apply functions
lst <- makePtree(df)                                           # nested list
dat <- lst2edge(lst)                                           # edgelist
dat <- rbind(dat, data.frame(a="root", b=names(lst)))          # add a root node 

## Make an igraph
g <- graph_from_data_frame(dat)

## Fix the names of the last level (they are lengthened in lst2edge
## so igraph doesn't show multiple incoming arrows to single nodes)
V(g)$name <- gsub(".*?([^\\.]+=[^=]+$)", "\\1", V(g)$name)
plot(g, layout=layout.reingold.tilford(g, root="root"),
     vertex.label.dist=-0.1, vertex.label.degree=c(rep(pi/2, 7), rep(c(pi/2, 3*pi/2), 4)))
```

[image]

You can adjust the position of the vertex labels with `vertex.label.degree` argument to the plotting function.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Thank you! I'll study the algorithm so next time I'll be capable to reproduce it.

Comment: @Valde great!  I added a way to make the graph have separate ending nodes as well.

Comment: Just great! Thank you again for your time, I'm learning a lot out of this!

Comment: @Valde I updated the `makePtree` function, it wasn't working correctly in cases where there were empty factor levels.

Comment: Great answer with lots of effort.

Comment: Be sure you read @AchimZeileis's comment. He is wiseR than almost all of us.

Comment: @nongkrong One more thing: I have noticed that when the tree is displayed, if you maximize the window there's a lot of room left blank that could be used to expand the tree so that the edges do not overlap among them when the tree has a lot of leafs. 

For instance, imagine that I have a big tree like this. Is there a way to separate more the leafs so that they make an efficient use of the free space? 

http://i60.tinypic.com/awqbee.png